# too few arguments for function error (updating data) CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

there's an error appearing in my code for update. too few argument for function.
I searched the net and I'm not sure if I'm passing the id.

Controller:

```
public function update()
  {
  
    if($this->Admin_model->update($this->input->post(null, true))){
     $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_msg', ['message' => 'User updated successfully', 'color' => 'green']);
   } else {
     $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_msg', ['message' => 'Error updating user.', 'color' => 'red']);
   }
   $this->admin_redirect('cms');
  }
```

Model:

```
public function update($id, $data)
  {
    $data['password'] = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    return $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
  }
```

Comment: Looking at your code, the update function effectively expects two parameters, "`$id`" and "`$data`", in the call you make from the controller you only pass one of those two values "`$this->input->post (null, true)`", it is necessary either that the update function equal the value of data to an empty array or null "`public function update($id = 0, $data = [])` "or that you pass it in the function to make it work

Comment: forgive my ignorance but, I thought this line of code $this->input->post (null, true) fetches all parameters? how can I pass the $id? TIA

Comment: Keep in mind that when you call `$this->input->post(null, true)` it is a separate method to which you created "update", that is, not by passing in the function to obtain the post two parameters means that you are passing in the update function, your function to update if or if it should receive the parameters that you configured, if you need some parameters you can match them to a default value as I put in the comment passed `public function update ($id = 0, $data = []) `that way you could call the function without passing values.

Comment: Another thing, your update does not have "where" if you do not add it you will update all the records, be sure to pass bin the values: 
`public function update($id, $data)
  {
    $data['password'] = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    return $this->db->where('id', $id)->update($this->table, $data);
  }` That way you will be using the two parameters that you specified in the function and the update would be correct

Comment: thanks a lot for the clarification! it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @WILLIAM, stated in a comment, your `update(...)` method expects 2 parameters yet one is passed.

Change your `update(...)` method to this:

```php
public function update($data)
  {

    $data['password'] = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $this->db->where('id', $data['id']);
    return $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
  }
```

This assumes that `'id'` is part of your HTML form.i.e:

```php
<input  type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your model **update** function with 2 params in the controller code, but it seems you are calling it only with one parameter $data value is missing.

**In below code:**

```
if($this->Admin_model->update(**$this->input->post(null, true)**))
```

It should be called with 2 values first one should be an ID that identifies the record that you want to update in your model, and another should be the data that would be updated within that record.

Hope! you got the answer.